# How to run xpath on element

Tags: javascript, html, dom, xpath

We all know that we can run execute xpath expression in console on the DOM element.

I wanted to know if we can to the same against an element.

lets say

`elem = $x("//li[@class='myclass' and .//a[text()='text_in_elem']])`

Now I want to execute a new xpath expression on `elem`.

Is it possible like we can do multiple chains of `.querySelector()`

Thanks.

Comment: I have been searching for a solution for that one. I figured a workaround, You can get all `descendant` nodes than do the second query
`$x('//*[@id="main"]/div[7]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/descendant::node() and contains(text()," ")')`